# Is a reverse question close enough to be a duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I just ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740652/how-do-i-sync-a-list-on-a-site-from-a-list-on-a-subsite-in-sharepoint). It sounded very familiar to me, so I checked the questions I've already answered, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630641/copying-list-items-from-master-list-to-sub-sites). So at first I was going to comment on it being a duplicate (since I'm nowhere near a point to vote for duplicates). But then I read it again, and noticed that it was not actually the same question. The second question is actually a reverse situation from the first question.

The usual criteria for a duplicate is "The answers for this question will be the same as on the other question". In the case of a reverse question, the answers might be similar (when they aren't just telling you to follow the same route and swap "X" for "Y" and vice versa), but they wouldn't be the same. The answer to the reverse question wouldn't answer the original question, and the original answer wouldn't necessarily answer the reverse question.

So, does a reverse question count as a duplicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the proposed duplicate doesn't answer the question as well, then it's not a duplicate

Comment: This. Closing questions as duplicates because they sound similar is destructive if the answers don't/won't/can't be the same. Similarly, two superficially-different questions might be closed if the answers will be identical.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a duplicate. The fact that the mechanism for solving the problem is identical doesn't matter, because it would be different use cases that would cause people to ask the question. So the people who want the "top down" approach would not be searching with the "sub site" question. So they would not be able to find the question.

You should comment on the question and link to the other question, just say "The answers [link]here will suffice."