# Option to migrate comment to answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, flags, hot-questions

A lot of times I see answers in comments, ***especially*** on questions from HNQ (Hot Network Questions). The trouble is they are sometimes helpful advice or may have many upvotes. I have been flagging such comments as "Other -> Answer in comments".

Should there be an option to migrate them? I remember there used to be a more specific flag for answers in comments, I'm not necessarily saying it should be added back.

Comment: Likely related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302271/add-an-answer-in-comments-flag-reason

Comment: No, you shouldn't

Comment: @Won't Ironically you've made an answer in the comments (possibly intentionally to explain your opinion), can you please explain why instead of just leaving a comment though?

Comment: Nah, don't want to spend the time.

Comment: **Do not raise flags like this on comments.** The only options moderators have for comment flags are to *delete* the comment or to *decline* the flag. Which do you expect them to do? Do you want them to *destroy value* by deleting the comment? I certainly don't. If you want to motivate someone who posted a useful comment to post an answer, ping them in the comments and ask for them to do so. Otherwise, post an answer yourself, giving them the credit, since all content on this  site is licensed under CC by-SA. (And no, there was never a flag for this.)

Answer (score 1):

> Should there be an option to migrate them?

I don't believe that such option is really necessary.

If you think it's worth it, just take the over comment and answer yourself, or encourage the commenter to write an answer by leaving another comment for them.
Usually you should probably flesh out a bit more about facts stated in the comment, since OP's had reasons to post a comment instead of an answer.

Most likely

- The question is *off-topic* for the site at all
- The question is *too broad* or *opinion based*

Comment: Did you mean "The answer"?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. If there's no _"The (definite) answer"_ comments are likely to appear.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand what you are saying now. I frequent HNQ so my experience is probably different, but at least on those you can find examples of complete and good (not great) answers in the comments. Just scrolling through I find this very quickly, https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39639/why-should-universal-income-be-universal#comment153377_39639 but you can find many more.

Comment: Again, if they're worth it and applicable there might even be canonical duplicates chosen. There are reasons why users might to close questions but at least leave a helpful comment before the question disappears into the _limbo_.

Comment: Oh, then I didn't get you, sorry. I am talking about *answers* in comments on questions, not *new questions* in comments on questions/answers.