# Why do I see so many answers in comments?

Tags: discussion

Why do I see so many answers in comments on SO? Aren't we supposed to answer questions in an answer post? Is it ok/should I flag these types of "answers?"

I know this is frustrating to me to be looking for questions to answer and then find one that's been "answered" in a comment. These also don't seem to garner an answer mark or upvotes as often.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4217/348196) and [Add an “answer in comments” flag reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302271/348196).

Comment: Ah my searching did not find those, thanks. In several cases these have been full blown answers with code. not anything that adds to the question. Which is why i'm wondering if these should be flagged. They are much more helpful and identifiable as a actual answer. I'm new here and don't want to go happy flagging stuff that should not be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark a comment as the answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-the-answer-to-a-question) -- If the "comment" isn't clear *why* it's not a full answer or it's clearly not then it's probably not an answer. **If** it is an answer it's yours for the taking, some people like to leave an additional comment asking for permission while others simply credit the comment(s). Exactly "why" is an opinion.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I probably over complicated my question I should have just asked if those should be flagged or if this was bad practice. I get the feeling from these links that people are doing this and it should be OK. I don't feel right copy and pasting these answers as it's not my answer and feels like a point grab.

Comment: @CM42 What I've seen done a few times, & have done myself several times, regarding "I don't feel right copy and pasting these answers as it's not my answer and feels like a point grab", is to acknowledge in an answer that it's coming from a comment (I personally use a link to both the user and the comment), & mark the answer by clicking the "community wiki" checkbox before posting. This way, I don't get any points for upvotes on it, so I don't need to feel guilty about this. I'm quite certain this is not what community wikis were designed for, but using this option works well for these cases.